# Wordwrap in Slick2d True Type font

Tags: java, slick2d

i am using Slick2d to make some simple Texts fly around the Monitor. 
For that i am using the TrueTypeFont class from Slick2D and the Fontclass from java.awt .
I am Trying to make a newline with the usual \n in a String. But this wont work. Has anyone figured out a way to do this:

For example:

```
awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20);
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);

        Color.white.bind();

        font.drawString(position.getX(),position.getY(),"Heyho, i want a \n chocolatecake",Color.black);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wordwrapping is implemented in the basic true type font class of Slick2D. Are you using the newest Slick2D version? In case you do and it's not working that either means you have to draw a second string or modify 
Slick2D's true type font class.

```
package org.newdawn.slick;



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.GLUtils;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.Renderer;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.SGL;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.BufferedImageUtil;

/**
 * A TrueType font implementation for Slick
 * 
 * @author James Chambers (Jimmy)
 * @author Jeremy Adams (elias4444)
 * @author Kevin Glass (kevglass)
 * @author Peter Korzuszek (genail)
 * @author David Muhar (bobjob)
 */
public class TrueTypeFont implements org.newdawn.slick.Font {
   public final static int
   ALIGN_LEFT = 0,
   ALIGN_RIGHT = 1,
   ALIGN_CENTER = 2;

   /** The renderer to use for all GL operations */
   private static final SGL GL = Renderer.get();

   /** Array that holds necessary information about the font characters */
   private IntObject[] charArray = new IntObject[256];

   /** Map of user defined font characters (Character <-> IntObject) */
   private Map customChars = new HashMap();

   /** Boolean flag on whether AntiAliasing is enabled or not */
   private boolean antiAlias;

   /** Font's size */
   private int fontSize = 0;

   /** Font's height */
   private int fontHeight = 0;

   /** Texture used to cache the font 0-255 characters */
   private Texture fontTexture;

   /** Default font texture width */
   private int textureWidth = 512;

   /** Default font texture height */
   private int textureHeight = 512;

   /** A reference to Java's AWT Font that we create our font texture from */
   private java.awt.Font font;

   /** The font metrics for our Java AWT font */
   private FontMetrics fontMetrics;

   /**
    * This is a special internal class that holds our necessary information for
    * the font characters. This includes width, height, and where the character
    * is stored on the font texture.
    */
   private class IntObject {
      /** Character's width */
      public int width;

      /** Character's height */
      public int height;

      /** Character's stored x position */
      public int storedX;

      /** Character's stored y position */
      public int storedY;
   }

   /**
    * Constructor for the TrueTypeFont class Pass in the preloaded standard
    * Java TrueType font, and whether you want it to be cached with
    * AntiAliasing applied.
    * 
    * @param font
    *            Standard Java AWT font
    * @param antiAlias
    *            Whether or not to apply AntiAliasing to the cached font
    * @param additionalChars
    *            Characters of font that will be used in addition of first 256 (by unicode).
    */
   public TrueTypeFont(java.awt.Font font, boolean antiAlias, char[] additionalChars) {
      GLUtils.checkGLContext();

      this.font = font;
      this.fontSize = font.getSize();
      this.antiAlias = antiAlias;

      createSet( additionalChars );
   }

   /**
    * Constructor for the TrueTypeFont class Pass in the preloaded standard
    * Java TrueType font, and whether you want it to be cached with
    * AntiAliasing applied.
    * 
    * @param font
    *            Standard Java AWT font
    * @param antiAlias
    *            Whether or not to apply AntiAliasing to the cached font
    */
   public TrueTypeFont(java.awt.Font font, boolean antiAlias) {
      this( font, antiAlias, null );
   }

   /**
    * Create a standard Java2D BufferedImage of the given character
    * 
    * @param ch
    *            The character to create a BufferedImage for
    * 
    * @return A BufferedImage containing the character
    */
   private BufferedImage getFontImage(char ch) {
      // Create a temporary image to extract the character's size
      BufferedImage tempfontImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) tempfontImage.getGraphics();
      if (antiAlias == true) {
         g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      }
      g.setFont(font);
      fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
      int charwidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(ch);

      if (charwidth <= 0) {
         charwidth = 1;
      }
      int charheight = fontMetrics.getHeight();
      if (charheight <= 0) {
         charheight = fontSize;
      }

      // Create another image holding the character we are creating
      BufferedImage fontImage;
      fontImage = new BufferedImage(charwidth, charheight,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D gt = (Graphics2D) fontImage.getGraphics();
      if (antiAlias == true) {
         gt.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      }
      gt.setFont(font);

      gt.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      int charx = 0;
      int chary = 0;
      gt.drawString(String.valueOf(ch), (charx), (chary)
            + fontMetrics.getAscent());

      return fontImage;

   }

   /**
    * Create and store the font
    * 
    * @param customCharsArray Characters that should be also added to the cache.
    */
   private void createSet( char[] customCharsArray ) {
      // If there are custom chars then I expand the font texture twice      
      if   (customCharsArray != null && customCharsArray.length > 0) {
         textureWidth *= 2;
      }

      // In any case this should be done in other way. Texture with size 512x512
      // can maintain only 256 characters with resolution of 32x32. The texture
      // size should be calculated dynamicaly by looking at character sizes. 

      try {

         BufferedImage imgTemp = new BufferedImage(textureWidth, textureHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) imgTemp.getGraphics();

         g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,1));
         g.fillRect(0,0,textureWidth,textureHeight);

         int rowHeight = 0;
         int positionX = 0;
         int positionY = 0;

         int customCharsLength = ( customCharsArray != null ) ? customCharsArray.length : 0; 

         for (int i = 0; i < 256 + customCharsLength; i++) {

            // get 0-255 characters and then custom characters
            char ch = ( i < 256 ) ? (char) i : customCharsArray[i-256];

            BufferedImage fontImage = getFontImage(ch);

            IntObject newIntObject = new IntObject();

            newIntObject.width = fontImage.getWidth();
            newIntObject.height = fontImage.getHeight();

            if (positionX + newIntObject.width >= textureWidth) {
               positionX = 0;
               positionY += rowHeight;
               rowHeight = 0;
            }

            newIntObject.storedX = positionX;
            newIntObject.storedY = positionY;

            if (newIntObject.height > fontHeight) {
               fontHeight = newIntObject.height;
            }

            if (newIntObject.height > rowHeight) {
               rowHeight = newIntObject.height;
            }

            // Draw it here
            g.drawImage(fontImage, positionX, positionY, null);

            positionX += newIntObject.width;

            if( i < 256 ) { // standard characters
               charArray[i] = newIntObject;
            } else { // custom characters
               customChars.put( new Character( ch ), newIntObject );
            }

            fontImage = null;
         }

         fontTexture = BufferedImageUtil
               .getTexture(font.toString(), imgTemp);

      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Failed to create font.");
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   /**
    * Draw a textured quad
    * 
    * @param drawX
    *            The left x position to draw to
    * @param drawY
    *            The top y position to draw to
    * @param drawX2
    *            The right x position to draw to
    * @param drawY2
    *            The bottom y position to draw to
    * @param srcX
    *            The left source x position to draw from
    * @param srcY
    *            The top source y position to draw from
    * @param srcX2
    *            The right source x position to draw from
    * @param srcY2
    *            The bottom source y position to draw from
    */
   private void drawQuad(float drawX, float drawY, float drawX2, float drawY2,
         float srcX, float srcY, float srcX2, float srcY2) {
      float DrawWidth = drawX2 - drawX;
      float DrawHeight = drawY2 - drawY;
      float TextureSrcX = srcX / textureWidth;
      float TextureSrcY = srcY / textureHeight;
      float SrcWidth = srcX2 - srcX;
      float SrcHeight = srcY2 - srcY;
      float RenderWidth = (SrcWidth / textureWidth);
      float RenderHeight = (SrcHeight / textureHeight);

      GL.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX, TextureSrcY);
      GL.glVertex2f(drawX, drawY);
      GL.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX, TextureSrcY + RenderHeight);
      GL.glVertex2f(drawX, drawY + DrawHeight);
      GL.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX + RenderWidth, TextureSrcY + RenderHeight);
      GL.glVertex2f(drawX + DrawWidth, drawY + DrawHeight);
      GL.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX + RenderWidth, TextureSrcY);
      GL.glVertex2f(drawX + DrawWidth, drawY);
   }

   /**
    * Get the width of a given String
    * 
    * @param whatchars
    *            The characters to get the width of
    * 
    * @return The width of the characters
    */
   public int getWidth(String whatchars) {
      int totalwidth = 0;
      IntObject intObject = null;
      int currentChar = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < whatchars.length(); i++) {
         currentChar = whatchars.charAt(i);
         if (currentChar < 256) {
            intObject = charArray[currentChar];
         } else {
            intObject = (IntObject)customChars.get( new Character( (char) currentChar ) );
         }

         if( intObject != null )
            totalwidth += intObject.width;
      }
      return totalwidth;
   }

   /**
    * Get the font's height
    * 
    * @return The height of the font
    */
   public int getHeight() {
      return fontHeight;
   }

   /**
    * Get the height of a String
    * 
    * @return The height of a given string
    */
   public int getHeight(String HeightString) {
      return fontHeight;
   }

   /**
    * Get the font's line height
    * 
    * @return The line height of the font
    */
   public int getLineHeight() {
      return fontHeight;
   }

   /**
    * Draw a string
    * 
    * @param x
    *            The x position to draw the string
    * @param y
    *            The y position to draw the string
    * @param whatchars
    *            The string to draw
    * @param color
    *            The color to draw the text
    */
   public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars,
         org.newdawn.slick.Color color) {
      GL.glPushMatrix();
      GL.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
      drawString(whatchars,color,0,whatchars.length()-1, ALIGN_LEFT);
      GL.glPopMatrix();
   }

   /**

    */
   public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars,
         org.newdawn.slick.Color color, int align) {
      GL.glPushMatrix();
      GL.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
      drawString(whatchars,color,0,whatchars.length()-1, align);
      GL.glPopMatrix();
   }
   /**
    * @see Font#drawString(float, float, String, org.newdawn.slick.Color, int, int)
    */
   public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars,
         org.newdawn.slick.Color color, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
      GL.glPushMatrix();
      GL.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
      drawString(whatchars, color, startIndex, endIndex, ALIGN_LEFT);
      GL.glPopMatrix();
   }
   /**

    */
   public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars,
         org.newdawn.slick.Color color, int startIndex, int endIndex, int align) {
      GL.glPushMatrix();
      GL.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
      drawString(whatchars, color, startIndex, endIndex, align);
      GL.glPopMatrix();
   }

   /**

    */
   public void drawString(String whatchars,
         org.newdawn.slick.Color color, int startIndex, int endIndex, int align) {
      color.bind();
      fontTexture.bind();

      IntObject intObject = null;
      int charCurrent, totalwidth = 0, i = startIndex, d;
      float startY = 0;

      GL.glBegin(SGL.GL_QUADS);

      switch (align) {
      case ALIGN_RIGHT: {
         d = -1;
         while (i < endIndex) {
            if (whatchars.charAt(i) == '\n') startY += fontHeight;
            i++;
         }
         break;
      }
      case ALIGN_CENTER: {
         for (int l = startIndex; l <= endIndex; l++) {
            charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(l);
            if (charCurrent == '\n') break;
            if (charCurrent < 256) {
               intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
            } else {
               intObject = (IntObject)customChars.get( new Character( (char) charCurrent ) );
            }
            totalwidth += intObject.width;
         }
         totalwidth /= -2;
      }
      case ALIGN_LEFT:
      default: {
         d = 1;
         break;
      }
      }
      //int totalwidth = 0;
      //for (int i = 0; i < whatchars.length(); i++) {
      while (i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex) {

         charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(i);
         if (charCurrent < 256) {
            intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
         } else {
            intObject = (IntObject)customChars.get( new Character( (char) charCurrent ) );
         } 

         if( intObject != null ) {
            if (d < 0) totalwidth += intObject.width * d;
               if (charCurrent == '\n') {
                  startY += fontHeight * d;
                  totalwidth = 0;
                  if (align == ALIGN_CENTER) {
                     for (int l = i+1; l <= endIndex; l++) {
                        charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(l);
                        if (charCurrent == '\n') break;
                        if (charCurrent < 256) {
                           intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
                        } else {
                           intObject = (IntObject)customChars.get( new Character( (char) charCurrent ) );
                        }
                        totalwidth += intObject.width;
                     }
                     totalwidth /= -2;
                  }
                  //if center get next lines total width/2;
               }
               else {
                  drawQuad(totalwidth, startY,
                        totalwidth + intObject.width,
                        startY + intObject.height, intObject.storedX,
                        intObject.storedY, intObject.storedX + intObject.width,
                        intObject.storedY + intObject.height);
                  if (d > 0) totalwidth += intObject.width * d ;
               }

            i += d;

         }
      }

      GL.glEnd();
   }

   /**
    * Draw a string
    * 
    * @param x
    *            The x position to draw the string
    * @param y
    *            The y position to draw the string
    * @param whatchars
    *            The string to draw
    */
   public void drawString(float x, float y, String whatchars) {
      drawString(x, y, whatchars, org.newdawn.slick.Color.white);
   }
}
```

This implementation allows you to use the \n character and furthermore allows you to use alignments. As stated above I think this should be implemented in the newest version of Slick2D in case you use an older what for whatever reasons you should modify the true type font class and it will allow you to use the \n character.

Source: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1828

Comment: Thank you very much